# Emacs copy JSON Value

Tags: json

For a JSON block, is there any way to extract the value with a simple keybinding?;)

For example, the function should return foo:bar

```
  "hukarz": "foo:bar",
```

Comment: you might be able to cobble something together for yourself with the `json-read-*` functions in `json.el` (included with Emacs) or [`json-snatcher`](https://github.com/Sterlingg/json-snatcher)

Comment: "...the function should return `foo:bar`": given what as input? a string of JSON? a buffer in some JSON mode? a file? something else?